# Is it possible to set the banner image on OpenSea through contract metadata?

Tags: cryptojs, nft, opensea

I know it is possible to set the smaller collection image using the contract metadata, but is there a way to set the larger banner image?

https://docs.opensea.io/docs/contract-level-metadata

I also know you can set it through the UI if you are the contract owner but the contract is being owned by a system account with no access to the private keys to add in MetaMask.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I'm trying to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

No...

You need to contract OpenSea directly to have them set the ownership of the collection to another wallet you control.